# GOOGLE CLOUD PLATFORM: How to get list of items from google cloud bucket using php without Client API

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, gcloud

I am trying to get filenames from my google cloud bucket without using client API by making simple cURL request. Can anyone write a simple code, how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

1. [Make the file public](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/making-data-public),
2. Copy link to the file,
3. Use the link to download the file with simple http request.

Note that this allows anyone who knows the link to download the file. I think that if you want to limit access to the file you will need to use the API.